# The number of paths with the same length in a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n^2$ vertices. For each vertex $v$ let's consider all paths $\mathcal{P}_{v}$ that contain $v$. Now we can define the following function
$$
f(v) = \max_{p \in \mathcal{P}_v} |p|,
$$
where $|p|$ defines the length of $p$.

I would like to prove that in the set of values of the function $f$, one of the numbers occurs at least $\sqrt{2}n$ times. How can I do it?

Comment: Is a "coherent graph" a connected graph?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, yes

Answer (score 1):

You could reason it this way.

Let $p$ be the length of a longest path $P$ of a connected graph $G$ of order $n^2$.

1. If $p\geq\sqrt{2}n$, then $f(v)=p$ for all vertices lying on $P$.
2. Let $p<\sqrt{2}n$.
   It is easy to see that for any vertex $v\in V(G)$ we have $f(v)>\frac{p}{2}$ (here we use the connectedness of $G$).
   Thus
   $$
   \frac{p}{2}< f(v)\leq p,
   $$
   that is, $f$ takes at most $\frac{p}{2}$ values.
   If $f(v)<\sqrt2 n$ for every $v\in V(G)$, then
   $$
   |V(G)|<\frac{p}{2}\cdot\sqrt2 n<\frac{\sqrt2 n}{2}\cdot\sqrt2 n=n^2.
   $$
   Contradiction.

**Edit.**
Let us prove that $f(v)>p/2$ for any vertex $v\in V(G)$.

If $v\in P$, then $f(v)=p>p/2$.
If $v\not\in P$, then there exists a path from $v$ to a vertex $w\in P$ ($G$ is a connected graph). The vertex $w$ splits the path into two parts, let us call them left $L$ and right $R$ parts. Let $|L|\geq|R|$ (otherwise we will rename these parts).
Now we see that $v$ lies on the path $vwL$ whose length is at least $1+p/2$.
In the figure, $|L|=3$, $|vwL|=5$, and $|uwL|=4$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I understand most of your proof, however I don't get why $f(v) > p/2$. Can you elaborate more on that, please?

Comment: Ok, I will complete my answer with this explanation.